# What will be the difference of the roots of this given equation?

Tags: roots

What will be the difference of the roots of the equation 
$$
(x^2 - 10x - 29)^{-1} + (x^2 - 10x - 45)^{-1} = 2(x^2 - 10x - 69)^{-1}
$$

I actually tried to solve it but it was too lengthy to calculate with the simple method I know. I want to solve it in less time coz someone told me that it could be solved in less time. Can someone help?

Comment: Hint: substitute $x^2-10x = y$ and solve for $y$ first.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got y = 39, and the roots as -3 and 13, so the difference of the roots = 16.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks a lot, I got y = 39, and the roots as -3 and 13, so the difference of the roots = 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2-10x-45=y$$ then

$$\frac{1}{y+16}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{2}{y-24}$$

$$(2y+16)(y-24)=(y+16)2y \rightarrow y=-6 $$

Can you finish?

Comment: Thanks I got y = -6 and the difference of the roots to be  16

Comment: The roots are -3 and 13

Comment: You are very welcome!